# how to ignore redirect after login and redirect another page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, redirect

I wonder how do I ignore a diversion from the server after performing a login and then redirects you to another page, have researched a lot about it and could not find something that really worked, already tried to use the window.location, window.location .href, window.location.assign but none works.
The best I could until now was only open a new page using window.open to the site that I want, but I keep getting redirected.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>ECORI LOGIN</TITLE>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        window.open("mypage.html");
    }
</script>

<BODY>
    <FORM action="http://mylogin.com/security/jspring_security_check" method="post" >
    Usuario: <INPUT type="text" name="j_username"><BR>
    Senha: <INPUT type="password" name="j_password"><BR>
    <INPUT type="submit" value="Login" onclick="function">
    </FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

All help is welcome and sorry for my english.
Thank so much!

Comment: This is not possible I'm afraid, as the redirect is happening after your visitor has already left your site.  You could try sending the form submission via AJAX instead of the default approach and have your application react to the contents of the response in an appropriate way.

Comment: Can someone help me? I do not have access to the server, everything should be done client-side making it difficult =/

Comment: someone would have the idea of how to resolve this error problem 500 ". In the" Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'header is present on the requested resource Origin' null 'Therefore is not allowed access. "Or can only solve accessing the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw one of the comments suggested using AJAX, this is just another way of doing this. xhr is basically AJAX but without the bells and whistles.  Honestly you should use AJAX.  It is much cleaner.

```
 function doPost(url, method, callback, data){
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.send(data);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            if(typeof callback() != 'undefined')
                callback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
}
function handleLogin(respObj){
console.log(respObj);
//Do what needs to be done here after form submit...
}
$(function(){
    $("form input:button").on('click', function(e){
        formid = "loginForm";
        var form = document.getElementById(formid);
        var formdata = new FormData(form);
        doPost("http://mylogin.com/security/jspring_security_check", "post",     "handleLogin", formdata);
    });
});
```

And I changed your form to this:

```
<FORM method="post" id="loginForm">
    Usuario: <INPUT type="text" name="j_username"><BR>
    Senha: <INPUT type="password" name="j_password"><BR>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Login">
</FORM>
```

If you want to use AJAX you would use this instead of doPost

```
formid = "loginForm";
var form = document.getElementById(formid);
var formdata = new FormData(form);
$.ajax({
url: 'http://mylogin.com/security/jspring_security_check',
data: formdata,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
type: 'POST',
success: function(data){
handleLogin(data);
}
});
```

Comment: very very thankyou, you helped me a lot, I really had no idea how to do, my unique problem now is error 500: "Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500."

Answer (score 0):

The act of submitting a form is basically telling the browser to leave the page, send the form data to wherever `action` is, ending up in that page. You have 2 options though:

1. Intercept your login using JavaScript and instead use AJAX to do the login. Once the server responds to your AJAX request, depending on the response, you can then redirect the user to wherever you want using JavaScript.
2. You appear to use Java. I believe you can change the configuration to redirect you to your desired page once login succeeds. It's a safer approach than hacking a JS solution. It's like

   ```
   form -(submit)-> jspring_security_check -(server redirect)-> final destination
   ```

Comment: Hello Joseph, thank you for answer, but how to create this function if i don't have acess to servlet, i don't have idea =/ sorry i'm begginer in AJAX